# How can I remove rows on more conditions in R?

Tags: r, delete-row, multiple-conditions

I have session id's, client id's, a conversion column and all with a specific date. I want to delete the rows after the last purchase of a client. My data looks as follows:

```
SessionId       ClientId        Conversion         Date
    1               1                0             05-01
    2               1                0             06-01
    3               1                0             07-01
    4               1                1             08-01
    5               1                0             09-01
    6               2                0             05-01 
    7               2                1             06-01
    8               2                0             07-01
    9               2                1             08-01
    10              2                0             09-01
```

As output I want:

```
SessionId       ClientId        Conversion         Date
    1               1                0             05-01
    2               1                0             06-01
    3               1                1             07-01
    6               2                0             05-01 
    7               2                1             06-01
    8               2                0             07-01
    9               2                1             08-01
```

I looks quite easy, but it has some conditions. Based on the client id, the sessions after the last purchase of a cutomer need to be deleted. I have many observations, so deleting after a particular date is not possible. It need to check every client id on when someone did a purchase.

I have no clue what kind of function I need to use for this. Maybe a certain kind of loop?

Hopefully someone can help me with this.

Comment: IN your expected, the Conversion should be 1 at '08-01'. (or am I wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is already ordered according to `Date`, for each `ClientId` we can select all the rows before the last conversion took place.

This can be done in base R :

```
subset(df, ave(Conversion == 1, ClientId, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) <= max(which(x))))
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ClientId) %>% filter(row_number() <= max(which(Conversion == 1)))
```

Or `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[seq_len(.N) <= max(which(Conversion == 1))], ClientId]
```

Answer (score 0):

We could try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(ClientId) %>%
     slice(seq_len(tail(which(Conversion == 1), 1)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SessionId = 1:10, ClientId = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Conversion = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Date = c("05-01", "06-01", "07-01", "08-01", 
"09-01", "05-01", "06-01", "07-01", "08-01", "09-01")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```